# How to pass hours and minutes to date command through -d option

Tags: bash, date

I know how to format a date in bash using the date command

```
date -d 20160304 +%Y%m%d
```

for example.  But now I want to pass a date and time and return the hours and minutes.  I know the output format I need is +%H%M, but I don't know how to format the date string and it is not in the man pages.

For example if I try any of these:

```
 date -d 201801010500 +%H%M
 date -d 20180101_0500 +%H%M 
 date -d 2018-01-01_0500 +%H%M 
 date -d 2018:01:01-05:00 +%H%M
```

I get an "invalid date" error.  When I search google I always find answer referring to the output format, not the input format...

Comment: `man date` is mandate.

Comment: Note that we need quotes around any argument that has spaces in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU date accepts these format, among others I'm sure

```
$ date -d '2018-02-16 12:34'
Fri Feb 16 12:34:00 EST 2018
$ date -d '2018-02-16T12:34:56'
Fri Feb 16 12:34:56 EST 2018
$ date -d '2018-02-16T12:34:56Z'
Fri Feb 16 07:34:56 EST 2018
```

In general, can't go wrong with ISO8601 time formats

I'm in Canada/Eastern time zone

Answer (score 2):

The `date` utility is pretty impressive in making sense of different arguments for the `-d` option.

Here is just one example:

```
$ date -d "20180101 05:00:00"
Mon Jan  1 05:00:00 +07 2018
```

Note `+07` is the local timezone.